# Onvif CLI/GUI for linux

Tags: linux, video-surveillance

I'm searching for tool capable of managing camera devices compliant with Onvif.

What I currently found is https://github.com/KoynovStas/onvif_srvd but it does not really covers anything, because cli requires to write almost raw SAML requests.

Do you know any user friendly tools for Onvif management?